# Why return is required in file system (fs) module in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js . I came across the below code in w3schools website.

```
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        **return** res.end();
      });

}).listen(8080);
```

Can you please explain the significance of return in fs.readFile's callback function in the above code. I tried with using return for res.end() and it still works normally.

Comment: In fs.readFile, I am doing res.end() and which the closes the response , but why do we need to return something from this function.

Comment: No idea where did you find this, but you dont have to return, also you cant return, its a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` statement is not needed in this case, as `res.end()` is the last statement - it makes no difference. Consider this case however:

```
fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
          return res.status(500).end();
        }
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
});
```

Here, in case of an error, we use `return res.status(500).end()` to make sure we do not execute any more code in that function and run into an "Headers have already been sent"-error. You could of course use `if/else` and don't use `return` in case of an error,  but I personally find the first option to be a bit cleaner.